# How to remove the blank space in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none,axis equal]

\addplot+[no markers,thick] table [y=y1, x=x]{p=0_basis.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code to draw a tikz figure as this:
[image]

How could I remove those blank space, to make the figure more compact?

Thanks

Comment: Where you have blank space? Your code can not be compiled, so we can only guess what is your problem. For test, draw  your graph with axis that you will see, where is your curve and where is blank space. Maybe is problem in `axis equal`.

Comment: Use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` (or anything 1.8 or after). `pgfplots` even gives you a warning that you lose functionality when you do not set this key.

Comment: use `hide axis` key

Comment: You might try specifying the width and height of the axis.  Note that pgfplots regards these as suggestions, not rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizontal space is added because `enlargelimits` is true by default. You get a lot of vertical space because of `axis equal` it seems. A workaround is to set `ymin` and `ymax` explicitly, I don't know of any more automatic ways of doing that, though there might be one. In the code below `clip=false` is added because otherwise half the thickness of the horizontal lines would be clipped away. Different values for `ymin`/`ymax` would make that unnecessary.

The red rectangle shows the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  hide axis,
  enlargelimits=false,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  axis equal,
  clip=false]

\addplot+[no markers,thick] table [y=y1, x=x]{
x y1
0 1
1 1
1 0
4 0
};

\end{axis}
\draw [red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The changes in Torbjørn's answer are already incorporated to the underlying code behind the `hide axis` key, which is set when using `axis lines=none`. `pgfplots` has an extensive mechanism to ensure backward compatibility, so that existing plots look the same even if the `pgfplots` package has been updated.

To take advantage of this, always set `pgfplots`' `compat` key. There is even a warning if you do not set it:

> ```
> Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
> ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} into 
> your preamble.
> ```

Without a setting for the `compat` key, `pgfplots` goes into a "fallback" mode, where all keys have the effect they had at the time they were introduced. Here, this means we are not seeing improvements to the `hide axis` key introduced in version 1.8.

Set `compat` to 1.8 or later (1.13 is current as of the time of writing) to access the improvements to the `hide axis` code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} % or anything >= 1.8

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none,axis equal]
\addplot+[no markers,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (2,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is recommended to set the key to the current version when you are creating the plot, unless you have a specific need for the older versions. This way, you get all the latest features/fixes, but if you revisit the document in the future, the plot will keep the same appearance until you choose to change the `compat` key setting.