# Unable to use ymin to plot a curve using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am experiencing difficulties to plot a curve using `pgfplots`. I am unable to remove the empty space under the x-axis.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line = center,
axis x line = center,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
thick,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
xmin=-5.5,
xmax=5.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=3,
axis equal, 
grid,
]
\addplot [
domain=-5.5:5.5, 
samples=100, 
color=colour3,
thick,
smooth,
]
{0.33*sin(10*deg(x))*x + 0.66*abs(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output

[image: output]

There is a lot of unused space under the x-axis despite that I used `\ymin=0`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with `pgfplots` but I'd guess the the option `axis equal` is interfering with `ymin`.

Comment: remove `axis=equal`   - - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298757/197451

Comment: You are asking for `axis equal` --- and the standard width/height ratio of the plot is something similar to 4:3 (if I remember well); the two things are incompatible. So either you renounce to `axis equal` or tweak the width and height of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line = center,
axis x line = center,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
thick,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
xmin=-5.5,
xmax=5.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=6,
%axis equal, 
grid,
]
\addplot [
domain=-5.5:5.5, 
samples=100, 
%color=colour3,
thick,
smooth,
]
{0.33*sin(10*deg(x))*x + 0.66*abs(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed.. Thanks!